# Uncaught ReferenceError: Showdown is not defined, ReactJS.NET

Tags: javascript, reactjs.net

**Problem:** I'm [working this tutorial](http://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html) to learn about React.js.  I've added the showdown.js file to the project correctly and proved it is loaded as a script file in the client browser.  When page loads and I look at the console it shows the error listed in the title.

**Environment:** MVC 4/5, Reactjs.NET

**JSX File Looks Like This:**

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var converter = new Showdown.converter(); <-- Error is here
    return (
      <div className="comment">
        <h2 className="commentAuthor">
            {this.props.author}
        </h2>
          {converter.makeHtml(this.props.children.toString())}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
var CommentList = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
          <div className="commentList">
            <Comment author="Daniel Lo Nigro">Hello ReactJS.NET World!</Comment>
            <Comment author="Pete Hunt">This is one comment</Comment>
            <Comment author="Jordan Walke">This is *another* comment</Comment>

          </div>
      );
    }
});

var CommentForm = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
          <div className="commentForm">
              Hello, world! I am a CommentForm.
          </div>
      );
    }
});


var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList />
        <CommentForm />
      </div>
    );
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

**Proof showdown.js file is sent to client Chrome Browser:**

[image: ShowdownLoaded]

**Proof the syntax is correct in JSX file**

The line of code  where exception is thrown is:

```
var converter = new Showdown.converter();
```

[image: ShowDownConvertor]

**Question**
How do I get a new instance of Showdown.convertor?

Comment: Did you happen to include the `showdown.js` script after your `Tutorial.jsx` in your index file?

Comment: @JanKlimo Yes that was the issue... I had the file loading after it was needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jan's suggestion above was right. This is what fixed the issue:

```html
<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <script src="https://fb.me/react-0.14.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content(" ~/Scripts/showdown.min.js ")"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content(" ~/Scripts/Tutorial.jsx ")"></script>
</body>
```

Note that showdown.js must come before the jsx file.